Best way to interact with a Mumar
This might be a bit of a broad question, but what’s the best way to interact with a Mumar at least nowadays? How can one passively and subtly demonstrate to him the beauty of Judaism such to inspire him to come back? Or should one completely ignore and disassociate from him? What do our rabbis say, especially modern day ones

Mumars as a rule seek to play into the hands of anti-semites against the Jews, among whom they initially find full support. Only rejection of the mumar by anti-semites and their full bancrupcy can cause him repent. But then there are cases of guys like Lot who end up creating Amon and Moav after bing rescued from Sodom.

I think this is too broad to be effectively answered. It just has too many variables.
